# In R, print vector in single quotes and comma separated

Tags: r, knitr, paste, single-quotes

Problem Statement: I'm creating a dynamic application in which user select inputs and they are passed into URL to filter data. User can select single or multiple values. I'm using `knitr::combine_words(Selected_Input, before = ",", and = "", sep = ",")` to get them in single quotes and comma separated. But facing issue when user selects single value (as described below):

```
#User selecting multiple values
Selected_Input <- c("Apple","Banana","Cherry")
knitr::combine_words(Selected_Input, before = ",", and = "", sep = ",")
```

Result: `'Apple','Banana','Cherry'` which works for my code.

But when user selects single value

```
#User selecting single value
Selected_Input <- c("Apple")
knitr::combine_words(Selected_Input, before = ",", and = "", sep = ",")
```

Result: `,Apple,` which doesn't work. As it should be single quoted.

I'm using this knitr::combine_words inside paste0 to create a dynamic URL. So I'm looking for a way which works inside paste0.

If I'm using `cat()` function inside `paste0` then the output doesn't work in my code. The url doesn't fall in place.

```
vector <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry")
out <- paste(sQuote(vector, FALSE), collapse=", ")
cat(out, "\n")
#> 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'

cat(toString(sQuote(vector, FALSE)))

paste0("url",cat(toString(sQuote(vector, FALSE))),"url")
```

Result: `'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'[1] "urlurl"`

Comment: The question needs to explain what the expected output is but maybe you want `cat(paste0("url", toString(sprintf("'%s'", vector)), "url"), "\n")` or maybe `paste0("url", toString(sprintf("'%s'", vector)), "url")` depending on what you want.   Do not put `cat` in the middle of an expression.

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```r
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry")
all_fruit_in_one <- paste0(paste0("'", fruits, "'"), collapse = ", ")
cat(all_fruit_in_one)
```

Output:

```r
'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'
```

Comment: how could I modify this to use double quotes instead of single quotes in my output? I'm having trouble with the syntax because I can't wrap " using " "

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `sQuote`:

> Single or double quote text by combining with appropriate single or
> double left and right quotation marks.

```r
vector <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry")
out <- paste(sQuote(vector, FALSE), collapse=", ")
cat(out, "\n")
#> 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `cat(toString(sQuote(vector, FALSE)))` still a great solution +1

Answer (score 2):

I think it was just because of a typo in your code, i.e., it should be `before = "'"` instead of `before = ","`.

```
> Selected_Input <- c("Apple","Banana","Cherry")
> knitr::combine_words(Selected_Input, before = "'", and = "", sep = ",")
'Apple','Banana','Cherry'

> Selected_Input <- c("Apple")
> knitr::combine_words(Selected_Input, before = "'", and = "", sep = ",")
'Apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf` to insert the quotes and then use `toString` (assuming that comma with a space is acceptable as the separator).  Optionally `cat` or `print` the result depending on exactly what you want; however, simply entering it into the console will print it.

```
toString(sprintf("'%s'", fruits))
## [1] "'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'"

toString(sprintf("'%s'", fruits[1]))
## [1] "'apple'"
```

This can also be expressed in terms of pipes:

```
fruits |> sprintf(fmt = "'%s'") |> toString()
## [1] "'apple', 'banana', 'cherry'"
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
fruits <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry")
```